# How to resize a state when using the map function in the mapproj library in R

Tags: r, dictionary

I am attempting to plot a single US state, California:

`map('state', region = c('CA')`

I get a nice plot:

[image]

However, the state is small.  I can't seem to find any arguments regarding how to resize the image.  I've attempted some common solutions that might be used within ggplot, such as

`map('state', region = c('CA'), height=600, width=800)`

but nothing changes.  Any advice would be lifesaving.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can use `ggplot2`, it's quite a bit easier to resize:

```
library(sp)
library(maps)
library(maptools)
library(ggplot2)

calif <- map_data('state', region="CA")
calif.df <- fortify(calif)

gg <- ggplot()
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=calif.df, map = calif.df, 
                    aes(map_id=region, x=long, y=lat), 
                    fill="white", color="black")
gg <- gg + coord_map()
gg <- gg + labs(x="", y="")
gg <- gg + theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent", color = NA),
                 panel.border = element_blank(),
                 panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent", color = NA),
                 panel.grid = element_blank(),
                 axis.text = element_blank(),
                 axis.ticks = element_blank(),
                 legend.position = "right")
gg
```

[image]

Comment: Aye. Silly software licensing issues preventing it from running automatically. I actually have the `rgeos` library installed so I always forget about this error. CRAN has binary packages for `rgeos`, so if you use that it should make this error go away. Otherwise, just use `gpclibPermit()` before the call to `fortify`.

Comment: IIRC, you'll either need to expand the polygons in the shapefile or do some interesting things with graphics devices if you have to go a non-`ggplot` route. I do all my cartographic work in `ggplot` now, so I'm not current if there is a "base `maps`" solution.

Comment: Thanks for the great solution (although I believe the mapproj library is ultimately based on ggplot2).  Thanks for advice on the strange license error!

Comment: Oh no. `mapproj` is mostly a C library with a small number of pure R functions.

Comment: Wow I didn't realize.  I did stuff along these lines:  "q <-choroplethr(DF, lod="state", num_buckets = 1)  
q <- q + scale_fill_gradient(high = "springgreen4", low= "grey90")  and thing came out okay.  I assumed it was all heavily based on ggplot, but now I suppose I was just using it "in" ggplot

Comment: btw -- can you tell me how to explicitly change the width and height of the state?  I can't seem to find the right solution

Comment: `ggsave` will let you save it at any size. on screen, it will auto-resize to the graphics device.